# GWT Validator with Editor Framework

Tags: validation, gwt, editor

Have anybody realized how editors and jsr 303 validation work with GWT 2.3
coming? Validation API was add to gwt sdk. But I am unable to validate entities using the editor framework. No matter what
I do the errors are never thrown from client side or server side.

Here is a code snippet:

```
public class P {

  public P() {}

  @Size(min=4)
  private String name;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

}
```

---

**PEditor**

```
public class PEditor extends Composite implements Editor<P> {

  private static PEditorUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(PEditorUiBinder.class);

  interface PEditorUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, PEditor> {}

  @UiField
  TextBox name;

  public PEditor() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

}
```

---

```
  PEditor pEditor;
  interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<P, PEditor> {}

  Driver driver = GWT.<Driver> create(Driver.class);

  public void onModuleLoad() {

    pEditor = new PEditor();
    driver.initialize(pEditor);
    P p = new P();
    driver.edit(p);
    pEditor.name.setText("G");
    driver.flush();

    if(driver.hasErrors()) {
        List<EditorError> errors = driver.getErrors();

        for (EditorError error : errors) {
          System.out.println(error.getMessage());

        }

    }
  }
```

---

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The Validation API, at least as of 2.3, doesn't build client side code for you – it is a tool that can be integrated on the server to make your server spit back errors in certain cases.

The call to `EditorDriver.hasErrors()` is just to check if any code has told the local delegates if there are errors – client-side validation can be implemented through this.

The most automatic case right now is when using RequestFactory - if you have the javax.validation jar (both api and sources) on your server classpath as well as a validation library (hibernate-validator and apache's bval are two such libraries), the Receiver callback will have `onViolation` called.

With RequestFactory being used to get violations from the server, the `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` can then be used to push errors to the UI, though the use of `HasEditorErrors` editor instances and wrappers, like `ValueBoxEditorDecorator`, or just by notifying the user through some mechanism (alert, banner, your debug sys.out.println, etc) when `onViolation` is called.

If using RPC, you can run the server validations on your own, and (as of 2.3) call `driver.setConstraintViolations` with the `ConstraintViolation` objects generated on the server from the validation process.