# GWT Editor Client Side Validation?

Tags: java, html, validation, gwt, gwt-editors

Using the Editor framework I found that you have to do client side validation yourself. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978473/gwt-validator-with-editor-framework) that deals with this topic.

**Do I really have to write all this code when I want to integrate the client side validation with the editor framework?**

```
Person newPerson = editorDriver.flush();

Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(newPerson, Default.class);

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>> tmpViolations = (Iterable<ConstraintViolation<?>>) (Set) violations;

if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
    editorDriver.setConstraintViolations(tmpViolations);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

That's one of the differences between libraries/toolkits and frameworks: the formers are lighter and less intrusive but require more glue code.